# ValueError: could not convert string to float: (-1,

Tags: python, linux, opengl, raspbian

New Python programmer here, Ive been trying to set up a 3d graphical display of the output of an MPU6050 gyroscope and accelerometer module on the Raspberry Pi. I found a Python script on the net that displays readings from the accelerometer, but I want display readings from the gyro only. I have a Python script running on the Pi, and a server (webpy) that sends data to my laptop. I run another Python script from the Windows command line on my laptop that uses PyGame and OpenGL to display the graphics.

When I run the gyro only script, instead of the PyGame window opening up and displaying the 3D representation, I get this error on the windows command prompt:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MPU6050.py", line 161, in <module>
    run()
  File "MPU6050.py", line 104, in run
    glRotate(float(x_angle), 1, 0, 0)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: (-1,
```

Ive spent days trying to get this to work, trying to convert a string to a float, but unsucessfully

This script works for reading the accelerometer data from the MPU6050 (run from the Pi):

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
import web
import smbus
import math

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

# Power management registers
power_mgmt_1 = 0x6b
power_mgmt_2 = 0x6c

bus = smbus.SMBus(0) # or bus = smbus.SMBus(1) for Revision 2 boards
address = 0x68       # This is the address value read via the i2cdetect command


def read_byte(adr):
    return bus.read_byte_data(address, adr)

def read_word(adr):
    high = bus.read_byte_data(address, adr)
    low = bus.read_byte_data(address, adr+1)
    val = (high << 8) + low
    return val

def read_word_2c(adr):
    val = read_word(adr)
    if (val >= 0x8000):
        return -((65535 - val) + 1)
    else:
        return val

def dist(a,b):
    return math.sqrt((a*a)+(b*b))

def get_y_rotation(x,y,z):
    radians = math.atan2(x, dist(y,z))
    return -math.degrees(radians)

def get_x_rotation(x,y,z):
    radians = math.atan2(y, dist(x,z))
    return math.degrees(radians)


class index:
    def GET(self):
        accel_xout = read_word_2c(0x3b)
        accel_yout = read_word_2c(0x3d)
        accel_zout = read_word_2c(0x3f)

        accel_xout_scaled = accel_xout / 16384.0
        accel_yout_scaled = accel_yout / 16384.0
        accel_zout_scaled = accel_zout / 16384.0

        return str(get_x_rotation(accel_xout_scaled, accel_yout_scaled, accel_zout_scaled))+" "+str(get_y_rotation(accel_xout_scaled, accel_yout_scaled, accel_zout_scaled))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Now wake the 6050 up as it starts in sleep mode
    bus.write_byte_data(address, power_mgmt_1, 0)

    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

This is the python script that I run on my laptop, and it works with the above code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pygame
import urllib
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from math import radians
from pygame.locals import *

SCREEN_SIZE = (800, 600)
SCALAR = .5
SCALAR2 = 0.2

def resize(width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(45.0, float(width) / height, 0.001, 10.0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluLookAt(0.0, 1.0, -5.0,
              0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
              0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

def init():
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
    glEnable(GL_BLEND)
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH)
    glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST)
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, (0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0));

def read_values():
    link = "http://192.168.1.65:8080" # Change this address to your settings
    f = urllib.urlopen(link)
    myfile = f.read()
    return myfile.split(" ")

def run():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE, HWSURFACE | OPENGL | DOUBLEBUF)
    resize(*SCREEN_SIZE)
    init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    cube = Cube((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (.5, .5, .7))
    angle = 0

    while True:
        then = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return
            if event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                return

        values = read_values()
        x_angle = values[0]
        y_angle = values[1]

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glColor((1.,1.,1.))
        glLineWidth(1)
        glBegin(GL_LINES)

        for x in range(-20, 22, 2):
            glVertex3f(x/10.,-1,-1)
            glVertex3f(x/10.,-1,1)

        for x in range(-20, 22, 2):
            glVertex3f(x/10.,-1, 1)
            glVertex3f(x/10., 1, 1)

        for z in range(-10, 12, 2):
            glVertex3f(-2, -1, z/10.)
            glVertex3f( 2, -1, z/10.)

        for z in range(-10, 12, 2):
            glVertex3f(-2, -1, z/10.)
            glVertex3f(-2,  1, z/10.)

        for z in range(-10, 12, 2):
            glVertex3f( 2, -1, z/10.)
            glVertex3f( 2,  1, z/10.)

        for y in range(-10, 12, 2):
            glVertex3f(-2, y/10., 1)
            glVertex3f( 2, y/10., 1)

        for y in range(-10, 12, 2):
            glVertex3f(-2, y/10., 1)
            glVertex3f(-2, y/10., -1)

        for y in range(-10, 12, 2):
            glVertex3f(2, y/10., 1)
            glVertex3f(2, y/10., -1)

        glEnd()
        glPushMatrix()
        glRotate(float(x_angle), 1, 0, 0)
        glRotate(-float(y_angle), 0, 0, 1)
        cube.render()
        glPopMatrix()
        pygame.display.flip()

class Cube(object):

    def __init__(self, position, color):
        self.position = position
        self.color = color

    # Cube information
    num_faces = 6

    vertices = [ (-1.0, -0.05, 0.5),
                 (1.0, -0.05, 0.5),
                 (1.0, 0.05, 0.5),
                 (-1.0, 0.05, 0.5),
                 (-1.0, -0.05, -0.5),
                 (1.0, -0.05, -0.5),
                 (1.0, 0.05, -0.5),
                 (-1.0, 0.05, -0.5) ]

    normals = [ (0.0, 0.0, +1.0),  # front
                (0.0, 0.0, -1.0),  # back
                (+1.0, 0.0, 0.0),  # right
                (-1.0, 0.0, 0.0),  # left
                (0.0, +1.0, 0.0),  # top
                (0.0, -1.0, 0.0) ]  # bottom

    vertex_indices = [ (0, 1, 2, 3),  # front
                       (4, 5, 6, 7),  # back
                       (1, 5, 6, 2),  # right
                       (0, 4, 7, 3),  # left
                       (3, 2, 6, 7),  # top
                       (0, 1, 5, 4) ]  # bottom

    def render(self):
        then = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        glColor(self.color)

        vertices = self.vertices

        # Draw all 6 faces of the cube
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)

        for face_no in xrange(self.num_faces):
            glNormal3dv(self.normals[face_no])
            v1, v2, v3, v4 = self.vertex_indices[face_no]
            glVertex(vertices[v1])
            glVertex(vertices[v2])
            glVertex(vertices[v3])
            glVertex(vertices[v4])
        glEnd()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

This is the code I modified to display only the gyro readings (run from the Raspberry Pi) which gives me the error in the windows command prompt:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import web
import smbus
import math

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

# Power management registers
power_mgmt_1 = 0x6b
power_mgmt_2 = 0x6c

bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # or bus = smbus.SMBus(1) for Revision 2 boards
address = 0x68       # This is the address value read via the i2cdetect command


def read_byte(adr):
    return bus.read_byte_data(address, adr)

def read_word(adr):
    high = bus.read_byte_data(address, adr)
    low = bus.read_byte_data(address, adr+1)
    val = (high << 8) + low
    return val

def read_word_2c(adr):
    val = read_word(adr)
    if (val >= 0x8000):
        return -((65535 - val) + 1)
    else:
        return val

class index:
    def GET(self):

        gyro_xout = read_word_2c(0x43)
        gyro_yout = read_word_2c(0x45)
        gyro_zout = read_word_2c(0x47)

        gyro_xout_scaled = gyro_xout / 131
        gyro_yout_scaled = gyro_yout / 131
        gyro_zout_scaled = gyro_zout / 131

        return gyro_xout_scaled, gyro_yout_scaled, gyro_zout_scaled


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Now wake the 6050 up as it starts in sleep mode
    bus.write_byte_data(address, power_mgmt_1, 0)

    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

I haven't changed anything in the code I run on the laptop, just the script I run on the Pi.

Comment: `x_angle` seems to be set to `"(-1"` which is obviously not a valid float, you have to remove the bracket first.

Comment: Looks like read_values() doesn't returns what you think.